# Multiple patents or a single patent?

Tags: multiple, single

If one has a software idea with perhaps several features that could be patented individually would it be best to file a single patent that describes all the features or to combine all of the features in one patent?

Answer (score 1):

If the features all apply to a single base product, it would be significantly less expensive and probably less troublesome to file a single application.

Please note that the 2014 Alice v. CLS Bank Supreme Court decision effectively eliminates patent protection for many kinds of "software" inventions under a revised understanding of 35 USC 101.

Answer (score 0):

It specifically depends on inventive concept to have a patent portfolio is a good idea but, if you have more than one different inventions then cover same in different patent. keep in mind that slight improvements are not separate invention one has to overcome inventive step to get patent granted.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, an examiner in the patent office will normally review previous patents to find those patents which are closest to the invention in which a patent is sought. If all the features of the invention can be found in a single patent, the examiner will reject the patent as lacking novelty (that is, it is exactly the same as what was previously known and therefore is not new).